# Raid 1 LV partially up and unable to repair, the down rimage is missing

Tags: linux, boot, debian, raid, lvm

I run a lvm raid1 on my old computer.

- pv: /dev/sda1 sdb1 sdc1
- vg: myvg
- lv: myvg/debian

The root partiion is myvg/debian, it is a raid1 on sdb1 and sdc1.
(`lvcreate --type raid1 -L 6G --name debian myvg /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1`)

Today, the system show

```
[    4.617444] device-mapper: raid: Failed to read superblock of device at position 1
```

while booting.

After I login, I saw parts of raid1 lv is labled *missing* in `/dev/mapper`:

```
root@home1:/dev/mapper# ls myvg-debian*
myvg-debian                       myvg-debian_rmeta_0
myvg-debian_rimage_0              myvg-debian_rmeta_1
myvg-debian_rimage_1              myvg-debian_rmeta_1-missing_0_0
myvg-debian_rimage_1-missing_0_0
```

`lsblk` show `debian_r{image,meta}_0` are still in `/dev/sdb1`.
Only the `debian_r{image,meta}_1` in `/dev/sdc1` is missing,
and the system can still up.

```
sdb                               8:16   0  37.3G  0 disk
└─sdb1                            8:17   0  37.3G  0 part
  ├─myvg-debian_rmeta_0          254:0    0     4M  0 lvm
  │ └─myvg-debian                254:6    0     6G  0 lvm  /
  └─myvg-debian_rimage_0         254:1    0     6G  0 lvm
    └─myvg-debian                254:6    0     6G  0 lvm  /
```

I can not find other error message with lvm related tool,
the output of lvdisplay and lvs seem well.

```
root@home1:/dev/mapper# lvs myvg/debian
  LV     VG   Attr       LSize Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  debian myvg rwi-aor-r- 6.00g                                    100.00         

root@home1:/dev/mapper# lvdisplay myvg/debian-a myvg/debian_r{image,meta}_1
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/myvg/debian
  LV Name                debian
  VG Name                myvg
  LV UUID                ICBMVi-VVUl-ICAg-CAgI-AgIC-gICA-IDVKaU
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time home1, 2023-03-04 21:13:03 +0800
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                6.00 GiB
  Current LE             1536
  Mirrored volumes       2
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           254:6

  --- Logical volume ---
  Internal LV Name       debian_rmeta_1
  VG Name                myvg
  LV UUID                JCBMVi-VVUl-ICAg-CAgI-AgIC-gICA-IDVKaU
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time home1, 2023-03-05 22:42:11 +0800
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                4.00 MiB
  Current LE             1
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           254:3

  --- Logical volume ---
  Internal LV Name       debian_rimage_1
  VG Name                myvg
  LV UUID                KCBMVi-VVUl-ICAg-CAgI-AgIC-gICA-IDVKaU
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time home1, 2023-03-05 22:42:11 +0800
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                6.00 GiB
  Current LE             1536
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           254:5
```

pv, vg, lv scan all show well too:

```
root@home1:/dev/mapper# pvscan
  PV /dev/sda1   VG myvg             lvm2 [<120.00 GiB / 5.58 GiB free]
  PV /dev/sdb1   VG myvg             lvm2 [<37.25 GiB / 1.99 GiB free]
  PV /dev/sdc1   VG myvg             lvm2 [<233.25 GiB / <187.24 GiB free]
  Total: 3 [<390.49 GiB] / in use: 3 [<390.49 GiB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]
root@home1:/dev/mapper# vgscan
  Found volume group "myvg" using metadata type lvm2
root@home1:/dev/mapper# lvscan -a
  ACTIVE            '/dev/myvg/swap' [3.72 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/myvg/debian' [6.00 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/myvg/debian_rmeta_0' [4.00 MiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/myvg/debian_rmeta_1' [4.00 MiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/myvg/debian_rimage_1' [6.00 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/myvg/debian_rimage_0' [6.00 GiB] inherit
```

lvchange syncaction check report nothing too:

```
root@home1:/dev/mapper# lvchange --syncaction check myvg/debian
root@home1:/dev/mapper# lvchange --syncaction repair myvg/debian
root@home1:/dev/mapper#
```

But I can not read `/dev/myvg/debian_rimage_1` in fact.
It return a IO error while reading it:

```
root@home1:/dev/mapper# dumpe2fs myvg-debian_rimage_1
dumpe2fs 1.46.2 (28-Feb-2021)
dumpe2fs: Input/output error while trying to open myvg-debian_rimage_1
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
```

If I try to repair it: `lvconvert --repair myvg/debian /dev/sdc1`,
it say that there are no enough space on /dev/sda1.
Yes, it does have no enough space in sda1, so I specify sdc1 as parameter,
but lvm ignore it.

When I boot with a live flash drive OS, I can see two *rimage*
have different last modified time in dumpe2fs.

while I can get this raid1 LV sync in the live flash drive OS,
it still can not up correctly in a normal boot.

Do someones have any ideas?

By the way,
It also report a `PV /dev/sdd1 not found` error sometimes,
because I remove a non-used /dev/sdc, sdd is sdc now.
I already `update-grub` and `update-initramfs`, but it still keep showing up.
I think the PV is distincted with its UUID,
the change path should not affect it,
though I can't figure out where did it save the `/dev/sdd1`;
I already update the initramfs and the grub.cfg.

Answer (score 0):

ok, I find the reason.
In initramfs boot phase, one of my disk (the missing lv's pv)
is up later than another.
In raid1, when one disk is ready,
the virtual block device (rootfs) become active.

Once the rootfs partition actived, it is mounted and the boot continue,
but the lvm raid1 partition in used <del>can not add more pv</del>
*(we can add the missing pv with `lvchange --refresh myvg/debian`)*,
so the missing leg of raid1 is labled missing.

To resolve the problem, just wait all pv up in initramfs.
We can create a script in `/etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-premount`
to wait all pv up.
(There is a [similar bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=918681)
in the debian bug system.)

The simple one is just sleep a little time:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
sleep 30
```

or detect the missing pv in the vg:
(rename the `vg` variable to your vg name.)

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# /etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-premount/vg-complete-wait

wait_interval='1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 5 10 30 60'

vg=myvg

lvm_pv_complete() {
        local vg=$1
        local LVM2_VG_MISSING_PV_COUNT
        eval $(lvm vgs -o vg_missing_pv_count --nameprefix --noheading $vg)
        if [ "$LVM2_VG_MISSING_PV_COUNT" -eq 0 ]
        then return 0
        else return $LVM2_VG_MISSING_PV_COUNT
        fi
}

for s in $wait_interval
do
        sleep $s
        lvm_pv_complete $vg && exit 0
        lvm_missing_pv_count=$?
done

. /scripts/functions
panic "lvm $vg miss $lvm_missing_pv_count pv"
```

In my condition, the slower pv usually take about 6 seconds to up.

All boot phases in initramfs (for debian) are documented in
[initramfs-tools(7)](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/initramfs-tools-core/initramfs-tools.7.en.html#Subdirectories) ,
and one can explore the initramfs or debug script
with the `break=premount` boot parameter.
See [initramfs-tools(7)#Debug](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/initramfs-tools-core/initramfs-tools.7.en.html#Debug) section.

### initramfs shell

To add boot parameter, appends the `break=premount` to the
`linux vmlinuz root=UUID=xxx` line in grub,
and boot script in initramfs will drop a shell for you,
or if the boot script face a fatal error.

In the shell, you can use `exit` command to continue the booting
when you solve the problem.
(Do not use the `<C-d>`, which would eof the whole boot script.)